# Enter key press issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, enter

In a form we have a textbox and a linkbutton. On the enter keypress on this text will have to fire the linkbutton click.

I have added a js code like this.

JS:

```
$(".SearchClass").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            eval($('.SearchButtonClass').attr('href'));
        }
    });
```

aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnSearch_Click" CssClass="SearchButtonClass"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CssClass="SearchClass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is working as expected in IE , but is not working in firefox. In firefox on button click its just reloading the page.

Edit : while debugging with firebug script debugger, on enter key press, its not entering into the keyup function

Comment: You don't need to use eval in your code.

Comment: @antyrat: then how to trigger the click..

Comment: I doubt that's a portable way to trigger a click event - you're assuming the browser will store it as javascript in the href which I've never heard of! Have you tried `$('.SearchButtonClass').click()` instead?

Comment: There's a `.click()` function for that. Any solution which calls for eval() is pretty much automatically WRONG and BAD.

Comment: @Rup: Now also its not working..

Comment: @MarcB: Now also its not working..

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox, the enter keypress is triggering the form submission. You'll need to prevent that - something like:

```
$($(".SearchClass").get(0).form).submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

However, if you have other ways to submit the form (like a submit button), then you'll also have to programatically submit the form from those elements as this code will block all other form submission methods.

Also for your link click event, just try something like:

```
$(".SearchClass").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        location.href = $('.SearchButtonClass').attr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's probably because of the javascript that the asp.net framework uses for form submission.

Comment: Try adding `return: false;` to your onkeyup method.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that `$(".SearchClass")` actually matched your element?

Comment: yes..its working in ie.. One more thing this whole thing is placed in the master page.